# Portable Flash Player For Raspberry PI?

Tags: games

I want to be able to flash ".swf" files on my Raspberry PI and I know that Chromium can play flash files but is there a "Portable" flash player so I can use".swf"'s without Chromium?

Please and Thank You for any answers!

Comment: your question has nothing to do with RPi .... it is a linux question .... you may be able to find an answer at sites dealing with linux

Comment: https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html has the projector flash apps for Linux but the RPI has an ARM processor, not a 64 or 32 bit.

Comment: Is their any particular reason you don’t want to use chromium?